# spring-cloud-gateway:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

when I am use spring-cloud-gateway, produced the following error:

```
2019-01-21 00:35:22.906 [reactor-http-server-epoll-6] ERROR org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler - Failed to handle request [POST xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 5
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.addWeightConfig(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:157)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.handle(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.lookup(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:224)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.combinePredicates(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:200)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:646)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:523)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:897)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:372)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:232)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:190)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:332)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:372)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:232)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:190)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:332)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlattenIterable.subscribe(MonoFlattenIterable.java:101)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMaterialize.subscribe(FluxMaterialize.java:40)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlattenIterable.subscribe(MonoFlattenIterable.java:101)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize.subscribe(FluxDematerialize.java:39)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
```

and here is the problem source code:

```java
config.ranges.clear();
config.ranges.add(0.0);

List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>(config.normalizedWeights.values());
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            Double currentWeight = values.get(i);
            Double previousRange = config.ranges.get(i);
            Double range = previousRange + currentWeight;
            config.ranges.add(range);
        }
```

I guess this may be due to concurrency but I didn't figure out how this happened.I want to know how this happened or there are other possible reasons for this problem to occur.

Comment: Where does `config.ranges` comes from?

Comment: I missed the code above,click [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/175006b59fe91d294078b5ad8209e95c33cb4d5a/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java#L150)can see the `config.ranges`

Answer (score 0):

This could because of the line `Double previousRange = config.ranges.get(i);` when you first run the loop and `i` is equal to 0.

Make sure the `config.ranges` is not empty when you want to access the first element of that list.

In the beginning of the loop, try logging or printing the size of `config.ranges` and compare it with `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Size of config.ranges - %d", format.ranges.size()));
    ...
```

If the size of `config.ranges` is in fact 0, then you will need better ways to implement whatever you are trying to implement.

Comment: I re-edited the code for the problem and it seems to be sure `config.ranges` is not empty,but the error log shows that the problem is indeed caused by that line.